# Получить все элементы раздела Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня есть инфоблок ид которого 3, внутри которого есть раздел с ид 16, как получить все его элементы

```
$arSelect = Array("ID","IBLOCK_ID","IBLOCK_SECTION_ID", "NAME", "OBJECT_LONGITUDE", "OBJECT_LATITUDE");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>3,"IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"=> 16, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ 
    $arProps = $ob->GetFields();  
     print_r($arProps);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*Формируем массив ид подразделов раздела*/
$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>3, 'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y', 'SECTION_ID'=>16);
$db_list = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, true);
while($ar_result = $db_list->GetNext())
{
    $arrayID[] = $ar_result['ID'];
}
//print_r($arrayID);
/*Формируем массив */
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_*");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>3, "SECTION_ID"=>$arrayID);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ 
    $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();  
}
```